# Boost Program Options link error

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

I am having trouble with linking `-lboost_program_options`. I cannot even compile the minimum example [`first.cpp`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/program_options/example/first.cpp).

Here is the cpp:

```
// Copyright Vladimir Prus 2002-2004.
// Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0.
// (See accompanying file LICENSE_1_0.txt
// or copy at http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)

/* The simplest usage of the library.
 */

#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
namespace po = boost::program_options;

#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

int main(int ac, char* av[])
{
    try {

        po::options_description desc("Allowed options");
        desc.add_options()
            ("help", "produce help message")
            ("compression", po::value<double>(), "set compression level")
        ;

        po::variables_map vm;    
        po::store(po::parse_command_line(ac, av, desc), vm);
        po::notify(vm);    

        if (vm.count("help")) {
            cout << desc << "\n";
            return 0;
        }

        if (vm.count("compression")) {
            cout << "Compression level was set to " 
                 << vm["compression"].as<double>() << ".\n";
        } else {
            cout << "Compression level was not set.\n";
        }
    }   
    catch(exception& e) {
        cerr << "error: " << e.what() << "\n";
        return 1;
    }   
    catch(...) {
        cerr << "Exception of unknown type!\n";
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

Here is my output:

```
    g++ -o first first.cpp -lboost_program_options
    /tmp/ccNDtU66.o: In function `main':
    first.cpp:(.text+0x6f): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::options_description(std::string const&, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
    /tmp/ccNDtU66.o: In function `boost::program_options::validation_error::validation_error(boost::program_options::validation_error::kind_t, std::string const&, std::string const&, int)':
    first.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options16validation_errorC2ENS1_6kind_tERKSsS4_i[_ZN5boost15program_options16validation_errorC5ENS1_6kind_tERKSsS4_i]+0x2e): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::validation_error::get_template(boost::program_options::validation_error::kind_t)'
    first.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options16validation_errorC2ENS1_6kind_tERKSsS4_i[_ZN5boost15program_options16validation_errorC5ENS1_6kind_tERKSsS4_i]+0x4c): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::error_with_option_name(std::string const&, std::string const&, std::string const&, int)'
    /tmp/ccNDtU66.o: In function `boost::program_options::variables_map::operator[](std::string const&) const':
    first.cpp:(.text._ZNK5boost15program_options13variables_mapixERKSs[_ZNK5boost15program_options13variables_mapixERKSs]+0x1f): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::abstract_variables_map::operator[](std::string const&) const'
    /tmp/ccNDtU66.o: In function `boost::program_options::basic_command_line_parser<char>::basic_command_line_parser(int, char const* const*)':
    first.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options25basic_command_line_parserIcEC2EiPKPKc[_ZN5boost15program_options25basic_command_line_parserIcEC5EiPKPKc]+0x76): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::detail::cmdline::cmdline(std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > const&)'
    /tmp/ccNDtU66.o: In function `boost::program_options::basic_command_line_parser<char>::extra_parser(boost::function1<std::pair<std::string, std::string>, std::string const&>)':
    first.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options25basic_command_line_parserIcE12extra_parserENS_9function1ISt4pairISsSsERKSsEE[_ZN5boost15program_options25basic_command_line_parserIcE12extra_parserENS_9function1ISt4pairISsSsERKSsEE]+0x33): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::detail::cmdline::set_additional_parser(boost::function1<std::pair<std::string, std::string>, std::string const&>)'
    /tmp/ccNDtU66.o: In function `std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > boost::program_options::to_internal<std::string>(std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > const&)':
    first.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options11to_internalISsEESt6vectorISsSaISsEERKS2_IT_SaIS5_EE[_ZN5boost15program_options11to_internalISsEESt6vectorISsSaISsEERKS2_IT_SaIS5_EE]+0x46): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::to_internal(std::string const&)'
    /tmp/ccNDtU66.o:(.rodata._ZTVN5boost15program_options11typed_valueIdcEE[_ZTVN5boost15program_options11typed_valueIdcEE]+0x38): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::value_semantic_codecvt_helper<char>::parse(boost::any&, std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> > const&, bool) const'
    /tmp/ccNDtU66.o:(.rodata._ZTVN5boost15program_options20invalid_option_valueE[_ZTVN5boost15program_options20invalid_option_valueE]+0x30): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::substitute_placeholders(std::string const&) const'
    /tmp/ccNDtU66.o:(.rodata._ZTVN5boost15program_options16validation_errorE[_ZTVN5boost15program_options16validation_errorE]+0x30): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::substitute_placeholders(std::string const&) const'
    /tmp/ccNDtU66.o: In function `boost::program_options::typed_value<double, char>::name() const':
    first.cpp:(.text._ZNK5boost15program_options11typed_valueIdcE4nameEv[_ZNK5boost15program_options11typed_valueIdcE4nameEv]+0x26): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::arg'
    /tmp/ccNDtU66.o: In function `void boost::program_options::validate<double, char>(boost::any&, std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&, double*, long)':
    first.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options8validateIdcEEvRNS_3anyERKSt6vectorISbIT0_St11char_traitsIS5_ESaIS5_EESaIS9_EEPT_l[_ZN5boost15program_options8validateIdcEEvRNS_3anyERKSt6vectorISbIT0_St11char_traitsIS5_ESaIS5_EESaIS9_EEPT_l]+0x128): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::invalid_option_value::invalid_option_value(std::string const&)'
    /tmp/ccNDtU66.o:(.rodata._ZTVN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options16validation_errorEEEEE[_ZTVN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options16validation_errorEEEEE]+0x38): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::substitute_placeholders(std::string const&) const'
    /tmp/ccNDtU66.o:(.rodata._ZTVN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options16validation_errorEEE[_ZTVN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options16validation_errorEEE]+0x30): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::substitute_placeholders(std::string const&) const'
    /tmp/ccNDtU66.o:(.rodata._ZTVN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options20invalid_option_valueEEEEE[_ZTVN5boost16exception_detail10clone_implINS0_19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options20invalid_option_valueEEEEE]+0x38): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::substitute_placeholders(std::string const&) const'
    /tmp/ccNDtU66.o:(.rodata._ZTVN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options20invalid_option_valueEEE[_ZTVN5boost16exception_detail19error_info_injectorINS_15program_options20invalid_option_valueEEE]+0x30): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::substitute_placeholders(std::string const&) const'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    Makefile:4: recipe for target 'first' failed
    make: *** [first] Error 1
```

How do I fix this?

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6400 CPU @ 2.70GHz

Comment: `http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/914905e8c91f660a` I can run it here, are you sure you have the library boost_program_options? Is it in a location where the linker can find it?

Comment: I do have the library under `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`.  I even tried directly link `g++ -o first first.cpp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_program_options.a` but still failed.

Comment: notice the command line I have `g++ -std=c++14 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread -lboost_program_options main.cpp` vs yours. Try `g++ -o first first.cpp -L"/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" -lboost_program_options`

Comment: I got the exact same error. But I noticed that it may be because I am using `g++-4.8` and boost may require higher version. After I switched to `g++-5` it compiles correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed I used `g++-4.8` and it seems that my version of boost (1.54.0) requires higher version. After I switched to `g++-5` it compiles normally.