# Linking error in boost program_options

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I'm trying to build a 3rd party C++ library from source, and it depends on Boost. In the very last step when building, I got errors like this:

```
[ 90%] Linking CXX executable Shannon_RNASeq_Cpp
CMakeFiles/Shannon_RNASeq_Cpp.dir/src/main.cpp.o: In function `command_line_for_find_rep(int, char**, Shannon_C_setting&, 
std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, 
std::allocator<char> >&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, 
std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)':
/home/lambda/Shannon_Cpp_RNA_seq/src/main.cpp:320: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::options_description(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
```

I searched other questions on StackOverflow (e.g. [Boost Program Options link error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46641763/boost-program-options-link-error)), and initially thought that it was caused by the different compilers used to build the non-header part of Boost, so I downloaded the source of Boost 1.68.0 and built it in my personal directory using the same compiler I used to build the 3rd party library (the compiler is gcc 8.2.0), and from the error message, I can tell that C++11 standard was used (you can see `cxx11` in the error message), so it can't be the case that compiler not supporting C++11 is causing the trouble, as supposed previously (e.g. [undefined reference to boost::program_options in xubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39591067/undefined-reference-to-boostprogram-options-in-xubuntu)). To build Boost with a custom compiler (the default compiler of the server is terribly outdated), I followed the instructions [here](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2018/08/07/compiling-boost-gcc-clang-macos/).

Some further search reveals that this is a linking problem. The 3rd party library must be built by CMake, and I followed the instruction in an answer to a previous question ([How to link C++ program with Boost using CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897839/how-to-link-c-program-with-boost-using-cmake)), by adding this line to `CMakeLists.txt` in the root directory of the 3rd party library:

```
target_link_libraries(Shannon_RNASeq_Cpp ${Boost_PROGRAM_OPTIONS_LIBRARY_RELEASE})
```

However, the same problem persists. I checked the file `CMakeCache.txt`, and confirmed that the desired compiler is used and `Boost_PROGRAM_OPTIONS_LIBRARY_RELEASE` points to the `libboost_program_options.so` in the directory where I put Boost 1.68.0 (the server has other older versions of Boost). I then used `make VERBOSE=1` to check the bash commands invoked while building the library. The command doesn't sound wrong; the Boost program_options library has been linked; here's the command from `make VERBOSE=1`:

```
/usr/bin/cmake3 -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/Shannon_RNASeq_Cpp.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
```

It's referring to something in `link.txt`, and here's what I found there:

```
/home/lambda/mylibs/bin/c++  -g  -rdynamic CMakeFiles/Shannon_RNASeq_Cpp.dir/src/main.cpp.o 
CMakeFiles/Shannon_RNASeq_Cpp.dir/src/run_tasks.cpp.o  -o 
Shannon_RNASeq_Cpp lib_shannon/libmulti_graph_handler.a 
lib_shannon/libcontig_graph_handler.a lib_shannon/libprimary_lib.a 
-lboost_program_options lib_shannon/libsparse_flow_handler.a 
-lglpk lib_shannon/libseq_graph_handler.a -lpthread 
-lboost_system -Wl,-Bstatic -lmetis -Wl,-Bdynamic -lboost_filesystem 
-lboost_program_options
```

So yes, Boost program_options has been linked (-lboost_program_options). I wonder if this is something wrong with program_options, since all errors that occurred at this stage are from program_options; I also linked to 2 other Boost compiled libraries, namely filesystem and system, and they do not appear in any error message I saw here.

I solved this problem myself (see my answer below), but new to CMake (and my only experiences with C++ is `Rcpp`), I don't know why it worked. Can someone please explain why switching to a static library worked? Also, when CMake linked to the default version of Boost on the server, it also by default used the `.so`s rather than the `.a`s, even though the `.a`s are available. Is there any way to tell CMake to use the `.a`s rather than the `.so`s? Are there other solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was to change all the `.so`s in `CMakeCache.txt` into `.a`s, like I changed `libboost_program_options.so` into `libboost_program_options.a`, and this error went away. Then the command from `make VERBOSE=1` became:

```
/home/lambda/mylibs/bin/c++  -g  -rdynamic CMakeFiles/Shannon_RNASeq_Cpp.dir/src/main.cpp.o 
CMakeFiles/Shannon_RNASeq_Cpp.dir/src/run_tasks.cpp.o  
-o Shannon_RNASeq_Cpp lib_shannon/libmulti_graph_handler.a 
lib_shannon/libcontig_graph_handler.a lib_shannon/libprimary_lib.a 
-Wl,-Bstatic -lboost_program_options lib_shannon/libsparse_flow_handler.a 
-Wl,-Bdynamic -lglpk lib_shannon/libseq_graph_handler.a -lpthread 
-Wl,-Bstatic -lboost_system -lmetis -lboost_filesystem -lboost_program_options -Wl,-Bdynamic
```